# MongoDB watch randomly crashes (Cursor session id is not the same as the operation context's session id)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I am connecting to my MongoDB with the official node driver.

I am trying to watch changes, both on a specific collection and a specific document. Both ways are experiencing this error.

My code works perfectly fine most of the time, but sometimes while it's idle it randomly crashes my whole app. I would like to understand why this is happening, and catch the error so it doesn't break my whole app. Unfortunately, it never points to a specific line in my code.

Here is one of my codes (simplified):

```
let watcher = q.watch({ids: [documentId]}).on("change", (changeEvent) => { 
    //only listen to update operations
    if (changeEvent.operationType !== 'update') return;
    console.log('document was updated');
    watcher.cursor.close();
});
```

Which gave me this error:

```
node:events:371
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

MongoServerError: Cursor session id (8c01dfe6-6a3e-479c-98ce-243d61ec24e4 - 6tctnoM1KQxUOgLaEIm7HYAvVSF3YGlrCMxn+SswizE=) is not the same as the operation context's session id (none)
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:463:30)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at processIncomingData (C:\project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
    at MessageStream._write (C:\project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChangeStream instance at:
    at closeWithError (C:\project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\change_stream.js:355:22)
    at processError (C:\project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\change_stream.js:445:12)
    at Readable.<anonymous> (C:\project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\change_stream.js:364:33)
    at Readable.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  operationTime: Timestamp { low: 1, high: 1629924381, unsigned: true },
  ok: 0,
  code: 13,
  codeName: 'Unauthorized',
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { low: 1, high: 1629924381, unsigned: true },
    signature: {
      hash: Binary {
        sub_type: 0,
        buffer: Buffer(20) [Uint8Array] [
          104,  40, 136,  32, 223, 251,
          247,  64,  47, 185, 197, 229,
          247,  96, 219, 103, 110, 116,
           65, 183
        ],
        position: 20
      },
      keyId: Long { low: 5, high: 1629063232, unsigned: false }
    }
  }
}
```

I also have the other code, which occasionally crashes the same way:

```
queueCollection.watch([{ $match: { operationType: "insert" }}])
    .on("change", (changeEvent) => { 
        console.debug('document added',currentlyProcessing?'currentlyProcessing':'notCurrentlyProcessing');
        if (!currentlyProcessing) processNextQueueItem();
    });
```

If anyone could explain why this error is happening, or how to catch and fix the watcher when it does, that would be great.

Comment: It looks like, after some time, your code's session becomes invalid and emits an 'error' event which is not caught (`.on("error")`)?, crashing your program.

Comment: @theusaf ah thanks, that sounds like it work to catch the error, I am trying it now (though unfortunately I just have to wait for it to trigger since it happens randomly). do you have any idea how I should reestablish the watch though, preferably with the same `change` and `error` functions still attached?

Comment: I don't have much experience with MongoDB, but perhaps calling some `connect()` or `login()` method again could fix it? Otherwise, recreating the client and watchers is the only other way I can think of currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how to prevent it, but here's how to hack your way around it:

```
//watches the collection for any inserted documents
function startWatcher (collection) {
    console.log('starting watcher');
    let watcher = collection.watch([{ $match: { operationType: "insert" }}])
        .on("change", (changeEvent) => {
            /*whatever you want to do when event is fired*/
        })
        //changestream connection died (cursor session id is not the same as the operation contexts session id)
        .on('error', e => {
            console.error('watcher died');

            //close current connection
            watcher.cursor.close();

            //restart new watcher
            startWatcher(collection);
        });
}

startWatcher(db.collection('collectionname'));
```